# creating chessboard pattern with tables in python

Tags: python, loops, multidimensional-array, nested-lists

I need to make a chessboard pattern filled with 0 and 1 but it it doesn't have to be square table
I need to get rows and columns from user

just an example:

```
1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0

0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1

1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0

0 1 0 1 0 1 0 1

1 0 1 0 1 0 1 0
```

I have the solution but I couldn't understand the last row of code (`table[i][j] = int(not table[i][j-1])`)
can we solve it using another method?

```
m = int(input("insert number of rows: "))
n = int(input("insert number of colomns: "))

table = list()

for i in range(0,m):

    if i%2 == 0 :
        table[i][0] = 1
    else:
        table[i][0] = 0

    for j in range(1,n):
        table[i][j] = int(not table[i][j-1])

print("print the table with chessboard pattern")
for i in range(0,m):
    for j in range(0,n):
        print(table[i][j],end='')
    print()
```

Comment: "not" switches True and False (actually it's slightly more complicated) and "int(True)" is 1 and "int(False)" is 0. Python defines the booleans to have these values. An alternative way to write this line is `table[i][j] = 1 - table[i][j-1]` which has the same effect here.

Answer (score 0):

You'll have a simpler time with a nested list comprehension that uses the `x` and `y` coordinates of the cell being generated and the modulo operator `%` to alternate between two values:

```
n_rows = n_cols = 5

table = [
    [((x + y + 1) % 2) for x in range(n_cols)]
    for y in range(n_rows)
]

for row in table:
    print(*row)
```

prints out

```
1 0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 1
0 1 0 1 0
1 0 1 0 1
```

The list comprehension can be written out as nested for loops, too.

```
table = []

for y in range(n_rows):
    row = []
    for x in range(n_cols):
        row.append((x + y + 1) % 2)
    table.append(row)
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have an error on line 6 because you can't assign a value to an index that doesn't exist..

You can do this instead:

```
m = int(input("insert number of rows: "))
n = int(input("insert number of colomns: "))

table = []

for i in range(m):
    if i%2==0:
        table.append([0+j%2 for j in range(n)])
    else:
        table.append([0+j%2 for j in range(1, n+1)])
```

You could also print it like this:

```
print("".join([str(row).replace('[', '').replace(']', '\n').replace(', ', ' ') for row in table]))
```